# Node fs cannot read file that was written from command output

Tags: node.js, git, fs

I'm setting up some Jasmine tests and I want to take my most recently changed files from a github commit, write them to a file, and read that file into my tests. 
This is what that looks like:

Add git changes to new-file.txt:

`git diff-tree --name-only -r --no-commit-id HEAD HEAD~1 > git-changes.txt`

Read changes to Node variable

`console.log( fs.readFileSync('./git-changes.txt', 'utf8') )`

When the file is logged to the console however, there's a space between each character, and the very first character is a `�`. When I copy paste the contents of git-changes.txt to a different new file however, and then read that with fs, everything works perfectly.

I'm assuming this is an encoding error, but does anyone have any idea why this is happening to these files?

Note: I have tried changing fs encoding to 'ascii' or 'binary' and the problem still persists.

Comment: It should be `utf-8`.

Comment: @Derek unfortunately that didn't work - no change.